# Idiomatic way of comparing tables in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am creating a function in PL/SQL and I need a set of data multiple time and only want to query the database once, so I store the data in a table:

```
TYPE number_tbl IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
CURRENTFOOS number_tbl;
...
SELECT B.FOO BULK COLLECT
  INTO CURRENTFOOS 
  FROM A, B
WHERE
...
```

Now I want to check if the table `CURRENTFOOS` contains some values, so I create two (or more) other tables:

```
BADFOOS      number_tbl := number_tbl (1, 2, 3); 
MONDAYFOOS   number_tbl := number_tbl (2, 3, 7, 8); 
INTERSECTION number_tbl;
```

and to check for bad foos and monday foos:

```
INTERSECTION := CURRENTFOOS MULTISET INTERSECT BADFOOS;

IF INTERSECTION.COUNT > 0 THEN
    RETURN -1; -- bad foo
END IF;

...some more steps...

INTERSECTION := CURRENTFOOS MULTISET INTERSECT MONDAYFOOS;

IF INTERSECTION.COUNT > 0 AND ISMONDAY THEN
    RETURN 1337; -- monday foo
END IF;
```

This is what I came up with after some tinkering.

So is this the idiomatic way to do what I want? Is there a less obscure way?

Comment: nothing wrong with using set functions with collections.  But this sample code is so generic that its hard to see the bigger picture (what is your function really trying to do)?  Do you really need to store in separate collections?  Not sure because we can't see what the function is ultimately trying to do.  You could do an intersect in SQL without storing in collections first, but again maybe you're checking these collections many times...need the whole function

Comment: @tbone Yes, I could do this in plan SQL, but the `SELECT` I use to fill `CURRENTFOOS` is rather large and I need the result ~5 times through the function, so I don't want to run the `SELECT` multiple times and I want the function to be as clear and easy to understand as possible. The function basically looks at a project and based on same dates and other data proceeds some business rules to finally return a number representing the state the project is currently in. It's a bunch of `SELECT` and `IF` statements in the end.

Comment: if your concern is readability, then nothing wrong with your approach imo.  Actually, the_slk's answer may be more understandable to the average developer (exists is more common than multiset intersect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXISTS is fast enough.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE number_tbl IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    currentfoos  number_tbl;
    badfoos      number_tbl;

    l_exists     NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSDATE);

    SELECT  LEVEL
    BULK    COLLECT INTO currentfoos 
    FROM    DUAL
    CONNECT BY
            LEVEL < 10000000;    -- 10 000 000

    SELECT  a_level
    BULK    COLLECT INTO badfoos 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  LEVEL AS a_level
        FROM    DUAL
        CONNECT BY
                LEVEL < 200000    -- 200 000
    )
    WHERE   a_level > 100000;     -- 100 000

    FOR indx IN badfoos.FIRST..badfoos.LAST LOOP
        IF currentfoos.EXISTS(badfoos(indx)) THEN
            l_exists := 1;

            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSDATE);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_exists);
END;
/*
2013-10-22 10:45:23
2013-10-22 10:45:28
1
*/
```